# New @DataJpaTest in spring-boot 1.4 and relation with application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm updating my code with the new Spring Boot 1.4 features, and in my integration tests I was trying to use the new `@DataJpaTest` annotation. I'm having problems with the .sql files that I would like to run, some of them for the integration tests only, and another one for the future production database.

In my integration tests I'm using the `@Sql` annotation, with the .sql files inside the `/src/test/resources` directory and the H2 in-memory database for it. For production I'm using the mysql database, and I have a `data-mysql.sql` file inside `/src/main/resources`.

When I run my integration tests, I was hoping to see only the files inside `/src/test/resources` being executed, but even my `data-mysql.sql` is being executed.

Is this a normal behaviour? Is there a simple to change this?

Sample code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Sql("/test-data.sql")
public class CdrIntegrationTest {
     // any tests here
}
```

And my "production" configs are these ones:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/prod
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By "production" configs are they just in the application.properties? By default when running a test using the SpringRunner and @DataJpaTest is that it will still bootstrap the ApplicationContext which loads those application.properties and as such try to load the data-{platform}.sql file during the testing. This document describes the order of properties being inspected: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html. The #1 is using a @TestPropertySource. As such you can create a h2-test.properties file in src/test/resources and define your datasource properties for it paying particular attention to the spring.datasource.platform.

Comment: Yes, the production configs are just in the application.properties file. What I don't understand is why is it loading the data-mysql.sql file if it loads for tests a H2 database? If it is because the spring.datasource.platform option, I tried taking it off, but then the data-mysql.sql doesn't run either in integration tests or application start. I saw the @TestPropertySource, but it seems to much for just one config to have some sql scripts running in integration tests and others in application start.